# Partial fraction for complex roots using the second order polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

$\frac{(s^2 +s +1)}{(s^2+4s+3)(s+1)}$

the answer has to be in a $\frac{A}{(s+1)} + \frac{Bs+C}{(s^2+4s+3)}$ form.
However i tried to solve it this way but end up with that there is no solution for this problem. For instance i get: $A=1+A$ to solve for A which is false. Please help me i spent a lot of time solving this question with different ways and have no ideas left.

Comment: Please add steps how you got $A=A+1.$ Otherwise no one can help...

Answer (score 0):

There must be some mistake in the question as $s^2+4s+3=(s+1)(s+3)$

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$\dfrac{s^2+s+1}{(s+1)(s^2+4s+3)}=\dfrac A{s+1}+\dfrac B{(s+1)^2}+\dfrac C{s+3}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{{{s}^{2}}+s+1}{\left( s+1\right) \, \left( {{s}^{2}}+4 s+3\right) }=\frac{7}{4 \left( s+3\right) }-\frac{3}{4 \left( s+1\right) }+\frac{1}{2 {{\left( s+1\right) }^{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\frac {s^2+s+1}{(s+1)(s^2+4s+3)}=\frac {A}{s+1}+ \frac {B}{(s+1)^2}+\frac {C}{s+3}$$

I have found $A=-3/4$, $B=1/2$ and $C=7/4$

Comment: nice! thanks! but how can i transform it to this form? $\frac{A}{(s+1)}+\frac{(Bs+C)}{s^2+4s+3}$

Comment: @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani Your answer is wrong

Comment: @Alek.  Fixed it

Comment: got it now! thanks so much @MohammadRiazi-Kermani

Comment: Thanks  for your attention.